# Validate input hidden field created by checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Model

```
[Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

creating an extra field

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
```

change the value on browser developer tools

```
<input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="\%74udhdy">
```

If any manual inject of the hidden value, by changing it to something else other than boolean true/false..keep a button on the page, action result return view

if controller wants to return view(model)...

yellow screen death...

How do we validate the extra hidden field created by checkbox control?

Update - Action method

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //Logic to verify user
    //incase of any issue append modelstate.addmodelerror()
     return View(model);
}
```

Server error

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.

String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Source Error: 


Line 29:             </li>
Line 30:             <li>
Line 31:                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
Line 32:                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
Line 33:             </li>

Source File: d:\Projects\MVCTestProject\MVCTestProject\Views\Account\Login.cshtml    Line: 31 

Stack Trace:
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think he is concerned about someone "manually" posting random values on the "RememberMe" field

Comment: Updated with question.. Yes as a part of vulnerability and best practice I would need to validate the field... no death screen !!

Comment: When do you get a yellow screen? If the value was not `true` or `false` then `ModelState.IsValid` would return `false` and a `ModelState.Error` would be added for the property - _The value xxx is not valid for "RemberMe"_. An exception is not thrown, and you can easily check it on the server before returning the view anyway.

Comment: No, it can't be, because the value in the model that I'm getting at server side is the checkbox value (id=rememberme), where as the change that is been made on the  extra field created  (name=rememberme)... but the MVC framework is using the extra field value to load the view , eventhough the model that is passed to it contains proper value.

Comment: Jay, can you please also show us the code you're using on the controller side?

Comment: What has the id got to do with it? Read my last comment again. If the checkbox is checked, the `RememberMe` will be set to `true` (and the value of the hidden input is ignored). If the checkbox is unchecked, then the value of the hidden input is posted back. If someone has tampered with it and changed it to `"xyz"`, binding fails and a `ModelState` error is added. No exception is thrown if you return the view. There is no 'yellow screen of death'

Comment: You can also reproduce this if you run MVC sample template project comes in visual studio... I just tried ..

Comment: Internet application template for ASP.NET MVC4 web application... Then run the project , goto login page, F12, modify the value of checkbox extra field, then type any username and password hit login

Comment: Have you checked `ModelState.IsValid` and handled the error? You can remove `ModelState` errors using `ModelState["RememberMe"].Errors.Clear();`. But if there is an error for `RememberMe`, then you know someone nasty is at work, so perhaps you should not worry that an exception is thrown, or redirect them to another page telling them to bugger off :)

Comment: @stephen Muecke you are correct, ModelState.IsValid is coming false.. Trying to catch the error, is there a way to catch the error and rectify before returning the view?

Comment: Lots of ways. To check for just that property - `if (ModelState.ContainsKey("RememberMe")) { ModelState["("RememberMe")) "].Errors.Clear(); }` or to get all errors you could use `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });`. But as I said, this would mean someone is tampering with you site, so it would be best to return them to an error page anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75473/discussion-between-jay-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: ModelState.SetModelValue("RememberMe", new ValueProviderResult("false", "", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); - Resetting the value and returning the view solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using the strongly typed `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` helper which has the signature

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
```

the helper only accepts a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`) resulting in the error when you return the view.

As this could only happen if a user was tampering with the hidden input (and in the case where the checkbox was unchecked), then its probably best to let the exception occur, or to redirect to a custom error page, however as your interested in how to return the view without the error, you can check if the model is valid in the controller and remove the associated error message

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // This will be hit if the checkbox is unchecked and the value of
    // the RememberMe hidden input is not "true" or "false"
    if (ModelState.ContainsKey("RememberMe"))
    {
      ModelState["RememberMe"].Errors.Clear(); } // Remove the model state error
      model.RememberMe = false; // set default when returning the view
    }
  }
  ....
  return View(model);
}
```